# How to include vertical line between two box using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add two images in two boxes separated by vertical line so that it appears as divided equally and disappear when viewed in smaller devices. Refer my sample code link below. Can you please let me know what i am missing.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box1">
            <p align="center"> box1
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <p class="vertical_line"> &nbsp </p>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box2">
            <p align="center"> box2
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    background: #000000; 
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-family: Helvetica, courier, Georgia, Serif,  "Times New Roman";
}
container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
}

vertical_line{
    border-right:1px solid #333;
    float:center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1px;
}

box1 {
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px ;
}


box2 {
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px ;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do <hr />?
Also, you're missing all the "." before your clases: .container-fluid, .vertical-line, .box1, .box2

Answer (score 0):

You can just give border-left to box-2 div. And then you can hide it on tablet devices.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box1">
          <p align="center"> box1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box2">
          <p align="center"> box2
        </div>
    </div>              
  </div>
</div>

.col-md-6{
  padding: 0
}
.box1,
.box2{
  background: #f5f5f5
}

.box2{
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
  .box2{
    border-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Check demo [here](http://codepen.io/sivadass/pen/vxmxmo).